# How do I create a page in a SharePoint host site from azure hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, client-object-model

When I run the following code from azure with the app permissions 'Full Control' I can successfully create a page in the parent SharePoint(online) site. If I change the permissions to 'Manage' at site collection scope or 'Write' for the Site Pages library I get Access Denied.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = (FileInfo)fsi;
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
fci.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
fci.Url = fileInfo.Name;
fci.Overwrite = true;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fileToUpload = folder.Files.Add(fci);               
clientContext.Load(fileToUpload);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try with design permission?

Comment: Hi, there is no design permission for apps sadly, the options are Read, Write, Manage, and Full Control. I can't use full control because I need to deploy this app to the SharePoint store where it is not allowed.